# Хочу вывести дату создания и дату редактирования таска, но выдает белеберду. Laravel+Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как убрать лишнее и по возможности кастомизировать?

```
<draggable :list="tasksProp" :options="{animation:200}"
                           tag="tbody"
                           @change="updateList">

                    <tr v-for="(task, index) in tasksProp" :key="task.id" >
                        <td scope="row">{{ task.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ task.title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ task.description }}</td>
                        <td>{{ task.created_at }}</td>
                        <td>{{ task.updated_at }}</td>
```

Comment: Это не белеберда, это дата в формате

Comment: посмотрите пример форматирования [даты](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-format-date-for-display/3586/5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой ответ обычно возвращается с БД (универсальный формат даты).
Вы можете форматировать его в необходимый при выводе из API в Laravel (используется [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/)):

```
'created_at' => $user->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Вы также можете форматировать дату на фронтэнде, например, через [Moment](https://momentjs.com/):

```
this.$moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ. Воспользовался Carbon.